# LED Light changes color on being turned on/off simultaneously

Tags: light, led-driver, lighting

What type of circuitry/driver is present in the lights that change color on being turned on/off ?

I have a LED tube light which cycles through 3 modes (i.e. color 1, color 2, both color). Its circuit utilities only one chip (i.e. 9934A 7101H8, SO-8 package, there is *Si* written on it) for the above effect.

I was unable to get the datasheet of the IC.

The IC seems to be connected in the following way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvjqRN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It's a [Dual P-Channel MOSFET](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70163/70163.pdf). There ought to be other circuitry controlling it.

Comment: @Unimportant, In all the cases there is a constant voltage across the IC and if there was other circuitry (for this effect), it must have produced some change.